# Why do I get an error when I add a new object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is how i add new object

```
 var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var student = await _db.Students.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(s => s.Marks)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.Subject)
            .Include(s => s.Marks)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.Teacher)
            .FirstAsync(s => s.Id == studentId);
        var userId = await GetUserId();
        var teacher = await _db.Teachers.Include(t => t.Subjects).AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == userId);
        var dbSubject = await _db.Subjects.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Name == subject);
        if (!student.Marks.Any(m => m.Date == dateTime && m.Subject.Name == subject))
        {
            var mark = new Mark
            {
                Subject = dbSubject,
                Value = value,
                Teacher = teacher,
                Date = dateTime
            };
            await _db.Marks.AddAsync(mark); // <==== Exception
            await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

But this method executes with an exception `"The instance of entity type 'Subject' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 6}' is already being tracked."`
Where do I attach the subject? I get it with AsNoTracking().
So how to fix this problem?

Comment: do you have any loop wrapping around your posted code? or is there any data loaded elsewhere (before) into that same DbContext?

Comment: @KingKing 1) no. 2) no, it is controller method

Comment: I suggest to remove `AsNoTracking`